# Getting unknown syntax error

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax

sorry for bothering, but I cant figure out what the freaking syntax error is and need someone elses clear mind for it.

Here is the source:

```
  var getCloseIt = document.querySelectorAll(".closeIt");

  $(getCloseIt).click(function() {
         var ImgElements = document.querySelector(".previews").getElementsByTagName("img");
         var i = 0;

         for (i ; i < ImgElements.length; i++) {
              if(ImgElements[i].src !== ""){
                   document.querySelector(".previews").className += " previews-full";
              }
              else{
                   continue;
              }
          }​ //Getting "Invalid or unexpected token" for this curly br.
   });
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You have an invalid character after the `}`. You can see it in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r49fe1jr/.

[image]

To fix the problem, just remove that character.

Comment: Haha thank you! I was running it through every debugger but left out jsfiddle.

Comment: What is that character? Why is it not showing in editors?

Comment: @SanchayKumar its character entity in HTML is `&#8203;` which is a unicode zero-width space - hence why most editors don't show it. http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm